# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete::__construct()

Tags: magento2.2

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter,
>   instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\generated\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\massDelete\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete.php:27
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\generated\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\massDelete\Interceptor.php(14):
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete->__construct(Object(Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory)) #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\massDelete\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete.php
>   on line 27
>
> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post.php

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;


class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('api_data', 'id');
    }

}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Colection.php

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'mageplaza_helloworld_post_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'post_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post', 'Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
    }

}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\MassDelete.php

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;


use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
/**
 * Class MassDisable
 */
class MassDelete  extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

> E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Delete.php

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;
class Delete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::delete');
    }
    /**
     * Delete action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post');
                $model->load($id);
                $model->delete();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The post has been deleted.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['post_id' => $id]);
            }
        }
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a post to delete.'));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to do di compile again but before do it please delete file and folder from generate/code and generate/metadata

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument X passed to __construct()

These errors are generating when you have **injected/remove** a new classes to `__construct()` function. But did not do di compile

So,You have to do di compile again but before do it please delete file and folder from **generate/code and generate/metadata**

Comment: I got similar error after doing di compile.